# Auto deploy a Liferay portlet

Tags: maven, liferay, portlet

We are working on building an Angular application and hosting it on Liferay. I have started example Liferay portals to go. So far I have developed a Liferay portlet using Maven. I was able to build a war for it and deployed it manually by copying the war file to `portal/deploy` directory. Similarly, when a portlet is built using Ant, once its built, its automatically deployed in the Liferay portal.

Is there a way to auto-deploy the maven built portlet, rather than copying the war file every time? If there is a way, what setting have to be changed in the pom file?

Edit:

By adding the following to pom file auto-deploy the portlet?

`<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.liferay.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>liferay-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${liferay.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <autoDeployDir>${liferay.auto.deploy.dir}</autoDeployDir>
                    <appServerDeployDir>${liferay.app.server.deploy.dir}</appServerDeployDir>
                    <appServerLibGlobalDir>${liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir}</appServerLibGlobalDir>
                    <appServerPortalDir>${liferay.app.server.portal.dir}</appServerPortalDir>
                    <liferayVersion>${liferay.version}</liferayVersion>
                    <pluginType>portlet</pluginType>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>maven-deploy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
</build>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `mvn clean install liferay:deploy` in maven, and it will be deployed to your Liferay server.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using eclipse you can install and use the `liferay sdk plugin` which provides a set of options for build, the most important is

1.`deploy`- copys war file to deploy dir

2.`direct-deploy` copys all files to their locations (jar's,jsp,classes and other static content)

Comment: I have added pom details to my question. Would adding those help me achieve my goal?